# How do I capture the query sent to Oracle in an SSIS Package?

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have deployed an SSIS package which has a query that pulls data from oracle. The query has some variables in it and I wanted to see what variable were being inputted at run time. Is there a way maybe via sql profiler that I can capture the query that sql server is sending out to Oracle when the sql job runs?

Comment: No but you can capture it on the Oracle side. Do you have a client tool that connects to Oracle? (SQL Developer?)

Comment: yes, but I don't have access to the v$ tables on the oracle side

Comment: In that case the only way I can think of is to add logging to your SSIS package to log the query (or variables) to the SSIS logging table.

Answer (score 1):

How are these variables being 'evaluated' when the SSIS package executed? I imagine you get this from a table or generating on the 'fly'.

You have the following option :

1. Capture them and assign them in SSIS variable(s)
2. In case you are doing something complex - create a variable something like - User::SQLCommand. In this case Use expression to generate the SQL String that needs to be executed in Oracle. Use this in your OLEDB Source Editor as "Sql command from variable" to execute the statement in Oracle
3. Use a SQL statement to insert the variable details captured in previous step in your intended audit table

--
Please mark if this answers your question!